# Listview not clickable when adding an ImageButton (android - xml)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-listview, android-imagebutton

I have a layout for a listview item.
I added an ImageButton to the layout, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTaskName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTaskDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#0E2DF5"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTaskStartTime"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start time"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#44FF00"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTaskDeadLine"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dead line"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#44FF00"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnTaskDone"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="345dp"
        android:background="@drawable/done_button_state_selector"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

The problem - when I add the ImageButton - the entire ListView becomes unclickable. I can only click the button.
I need both the ListView and the button to be clickable, because im using them for different purposes.

I tried putting the ImageButton in one FrameLayout, everything else in another FrameLayout, and both of the FrameLayouts in on big FrameLayout. Still nothing

I would be happy to hear any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a recyclerView instead it allows for more flexibility, you can have your recyclerView in your xml code like so

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar" />
```

Then you set it up like so with java code

```
RecyclerView recycler;
CustomAdapter adapter;
List<CustomModel> models = new ArrayList<>();

private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kids_search);

    recycler= findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    

    adapter = new CustomAdapter (models);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recycler.setAdapter(searchAdapter);

}
```

So you create a model class to hold variables for each list item to show then you populate the models ArrayList with those models.
Here is how the the most important customAdapter class should look like

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<CustomModel> customModels;
Context context;

public CustomAdapter(List<ChildModel> childModels) {
    this.childModels = childModels;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_child, parent, false);
    context = parent.getContext();
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final CustomModel customModel = customModels.get(position);
    
    holder.tvTaskName.setText(customModel.getTaskName());
    holder.tvTaskDescription.setText(customModel.getDescreption());
    holder.tvTaskStartTime.setText(customModel.getStartTime());
    holder.tvTaskDeadLine.setText(customModel.getDeadLine());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Here the list item is clicked
        }
    });

    holder.btnTaskDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Here the imageButton is clicked
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return childModels.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvTaskName;
    TextView tvTaskDescription;
    TextView tvTaskStartTime;
    TextView tvTaskDeadLine;
    ImageButton btnTaskDone;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvTaskName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTaskName);
        tvTaskDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTaskDescription);
        tvTaskStartTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTaskStartTime);
        tvTaskDeadLine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTaskDescription);
        btnTaskDone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnTaskDone);
    }
}
```

}

Hope this helps